# Show and Hide a <div> in xs view, with a button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, hide, show, sidebar

I have created a Bootstrap Template where there is a "sidebar" div (col-lg-3) and a content at the right (col-lg-9).
In the xs view all the columns are 12, **how can I insert a button that hide and show the content in the sidebar div just in the xs view at the click on it?**

I don't know Javascript or jQuery, someone can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: do you want the button to just hide the sidebar or also expand the content at the same time? please elaborate

Comment: Hi @Aziz! Start with hide and if the user click, show the content of the div that was hide before the click.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap, you might want to check out the Collapse plugin:  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

There is a pretty simple example, but you'd want to set it up like this:

*note that you want to add the `visible-xs` class to the button, so that it is only displayed on xs screens.  Additionally, I added the `in` class on the div that collapses, so that is shows by default (otherwise it would be hidden on all screen sizes).

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary visible-xs" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            *Button only visible on xs*
       </button>
       <div class="collapse in" id="collapseExample">
           *sidebar content*
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-9">
       *content in col-lg-9*
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of the above code.  Make sure the screen size is small enough, otherwise the button will be hidden.  Click the button to toggle the visibility of col-lg-3 content.  http://jsfiddle.net/7v7p744L/1/

Comment: You're welcome.  Could you please accept this answer if it is the solution you were looking for? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could just add the hidden class to the button and say at what size you want it to take effect.

eg: 
   *hidden in xs

*hidden in sm

Comment: Thanke you, I have created a class ".collapse-xs {display: none; visibility: hidden;}" only for xs mood. ;)

Comment: Display: none auto makes visibility hidden.